# I'Fatal error: Class not found

Tags: php, fatal-error, classnotfound

I'm trying to install an older script that is freeware I found on the net. I've had to go through and update it for php 5 updates, however, I am stuck on the next error I've gotten. Hopefully you all can give me some insight as I'm really new at all of this.

I am getting the following error:

> Fatal error: Class 'com:wodchatsheet1Driver' not found in /home/wodchat1/wod-chat.com/classes/Database.php on line 49

Here is a link to the Database.php file: http://www.fileswap.com/dl/R44kEh0sWe/

I can't figure it out and I've been trying for a day and a half. The writer of the script's e-mail is bouncing.

Thanks again everyone!

Comment: That error simply states that the PHP file where that class is defined hasn't been included. Look for it on your code base and make sure to include it.

Comment: I hate to sound stupid, but I am really ignorant to php. What should I be looking for exactly? I've checked everything and it looks correct, the paths look correct etc. 
Sorry for the newbie questions :-\

Comment: @KeesterLabeau - does the Database.php file contain a class called `com:wodchatsheet1Driver`? The problem is that something in that file is creating an object of that class, and PHP can't find a definition for it anywhere.

Comment: @andrewsi - I did a quick search in notepad++ but did not see it. The error refers to a line 49 in Database.php and this is what is on that particular line: $this->dbd = new $driver($this->name,$this->host,$user,$passwd,$persistent);

Comment: @KeesterLabeau - that line is creating a new object, of a type that's defined in `$driver`, which I assume is set to `com:wodchatsheet1Driver` somewhere. About the only useful suggestion I can make is that you search all the files you've downloaded for `wodchatsheet1Driver` and see if it's present anywhere in there.

Comment: @KeesterLabeau - also, you say you're updating the code for PHP5. Does that mean it worked before, do you know?

Comment: @andrewsi Yes it worked before and the site I downloaded it from is still up and functioning at http://sheetgen.dalines.net/. Basically all I had to do was fix the ereg / preg issue. Do you know once I find it what I should check / do? There's quite a few files in this package to search through

Comment: So the only changes you've made have been ereg and preg? That would suggest that the issue isn't with a missing class, but that the amends you've made there aren't working as you'd expect. Maybe the class name is being dynamically generated, and there's a problem in the regex that's supposed to generate it? That would explain the `com:` at the start, which isn't something I've seen before.

Comment: @andrewsi - I did find this : function DBConnect()
 {
  require_once(CLASSES.'Database.php');
  $settings = $this->conf['database'];
  $connstring = $settings['driver'].":".$settings['server'].":".$settings['name'];
  return new Database($connstring,$settings['user'],$settings['password'],true);
 }

Comment: @KeesterLabeau - that looks like the function it's calling, doesn't it? It's looking to include a file called Database.php, in a CLASSES subdirectory.... How about you add an `echo CLASSES.'Database.php';` right after that `require_once` call to see if that echos anything useful?

Comment: @andrewsi - Okay, let me try this again. I'll reupload the files fresh and see what the original error is.

Comment: @andrewsi - so I have done a fresh install and the errors that I am getting are many. The reason that I changed the ereg to preg was because of this first error: Deprecated: Function ereg() is deprecated in /home/wodchat1/wod-chat.com/classes/Database.php on line 57

The other errors are here: http://www.wod-chat.com/

Thank you for your help, I can't tell you how much I appreciate it.

Comment: @KeesterLabeau it looks like you've got two errors there; the ereg one, and an include issue. Can you add the ereg to the question, and I'll see if I can figure it out? (That will also remove the session warnings, too, I'll wager). Otherwise, it's looking for a file called `SimpleTemplate.php`, which should be in the same directory as `VoodooTemplate.php`, I think.